# cannot initialize a variable of type 'Node *' with an rvalue of type 'const Node *'

Tags: c++, reference

What is the problem here, &head should yield a pointer to a Node and that is the type of cur but apparently there is a type mismatch?

I am trying to print the elements of a linked list using its head

```
void printList(const Node& head){
  Node* cur = &head;
  cout<<"[ ";
  while(!(cur==0)){
    cout<<cur->x<<" ";
    cur = cur->next;
  }
  cout<<"]"<<endl;
}
```

cannot initialize a variable of type 'Node *' with an rvalue of type 'const Node *' is the error

Comment: Head is const reference. You can't assign it to a non const variable.

Comment: Change the type of `cur` to `const Node*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do 
`Node* cur = head;`
or 
`const Node* cur = &head;`

This is because head is a const reference  and you can't assign it to plain cur(which is  NODE*).